# Coffeelint says I have implicit parens?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, coffeelint

Coffeelint is telling me I have implicit parens. I'm trying to find what is causing this error.

```
#309: Implicit parens are forbidden.
```

Here's my code:

```
((factory) ->
  if typeof module == 'object' and module.exports
    module.exports = factory
  else
    factory(Highcharts)
  return
)(Highcharts) ->
...
  if seriesTypes.map
    seriesTypes.map::exportKey = 'name'
  if seriesTypes.mapbubble
    seriesTypes.mapbubble::exportKey = 'name'
  if seriesTypes.treemap
    seriesTypes.treemap::exportKey = 'name'
  return
###The entire block over code is one function.
```

Anyone give this a shot?

Comment: Please post your code itself in the question, not just a link to it. You can [edit] your post.

Comment: What's a problem? I checked your code out with coffeelint and it said "Your code is lint free!"

Comment: Coffeelint is set to catch implicit parens. I can't ignore the tests because this is for an application with their own standards. @SergeyMetlov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's an issue with your code. Look at JS generated:

```
(function(factory) {
  if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = factory;
  } else {
    factory(Highcharts);
  }
})(Highcharts)(function() {
  ...
});
```

As the first function returns `undefined` there's an error trying to call `undefined` as a function.

Actually **no_implicit_parens** is for:

```
# This rule prohibits implicit parens on function calls.

# Some folks don't like this style of coding.
myFunction a, b, c

# And would rather it always be written like this:
myFunction(a, b, c)
```

With this option on, you must put brackets around any arguments list of any function call.
To make your code working you may do the following:

```
((factory) ->
  ...
)(Highcharts(->
  ...
))
```

These brackets around the callback function do the trick. But as I said, I'm sure there's an issue with your code and the fix actually makes no much sense to me :)

Comment: The code is working for me but I couldn't pass the coffeelint test. I figured this out about a minute before you answered. Thanks for the help though, your solution is the correct one.